# Azure Communication Services - An error occurred while trying to fulfill the search request

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

We have four environments and I've been able to allocate phone numbers for each one of them except for prod. I'm getting the following strange error:

> An error occurred while trying to fulfill the search request.

What's wrong? It's not very descriptive. Is it possible that Azure ran out of numbers?

These are the settings I used for all numbers:

- Country or region: United States
- Use case: An application will be making calls or sending SMS messages
- Number type: Toll-free ($2/month)
- Calling: N/A
- SMS: Send and receive SMS

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the environments under the same tenant or not?

There is a limit of 1 phone number per tenant, however, if you are sure your subscription is eligible as mentioned in the documentation here [Acquiring phone number subscription eligibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/numbers/sub-eligibility-number-capability), you can still acquire more phone numbers by going through the manual process as described here [Manual phone number acquisition process](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/tree/master/Forms)

In summary, you need to:

1. Download the right form and fill it with required information. For example, you can use the following form [ACS-Manual-Number-Acquisition-Form-US-UK-CA-DK](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/blob/master/Forms/ACS-Manual-Number-Acquisition-Form-US-UK-CA-DK.docx) to request numbers from the US, UK, CA, or DK.
2. After filing the form, you need to send it via email to the mentioned email inside the form

Comment: I filled the form and will let you know when they respond back in 2-3 days. Thanks :)